# How to set custom Date to react-datepicker?

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I'm receiving a date from our api in this format: `2022-06-08`

I want to set this as initial value in `react-datepicker`
but its giving the following error:

> invalid time/date error

Here is my code

```
const Datepicker = ({ date }: any) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(2022-06-08)

  return <DatePicker selected={data} onChange={(e: Date) => setData(e)} />
}
```

Please help !!!

Comment: Are you shure e is Date type? Dont you need e.target.value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DatePicker expects a [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?retiredLocale=nl) object, so you'll need to convert it first:

```
const dateObject = new Date('2022-06-08');
return <DatePicker selected={dateObject} onChange={(e: Date) => setData(e)} />
```